# How to take out specific keys from an association list

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm not permitted to use certain functions, like filter or remove, but have managed to write this so far.

```
(define (keys alist)
  (cond [(empty? alist) empty]
        [else (cons (first (first alist)) (keys (rest alist)))]))

(define (list=? list1 list2)
  (cond [(and (empty? list1) (empty? list2)) true]
        [else (and (cons? list1) (cons? list2)
                   (equal? (first list1) (first list2))
                   (list=? (rest list1) (rest list2)))]))

(define (remove-duplicates l)
  (cond ((empty? l)
         '())
        ((member (first l) (rest l))
         (remove-duplicates (rest l)))
        (else
         (cons (first l) (remove-duplicates (rest l))))))

(define (unique-keys alst1 alst2)
  (cond
    [(empty? alst1) (keys alst2)]
    [(empty? alst2) (keys alst1)]
    [(list=? alst1 alst2) empty]
    [(list=? (keys alst1)(keys alst2)) empty]
    [(member? (first (keys alst1)) (keys alst2)) (remove-duplicates (append 
                                                                     (keys alst1)(keys alst2)))]
    [else (unique-keys (rest (keys alst1)) alst2)]))
```

My code gives :

```
(unique-keys (list (list 1 "a") (list 2 "b") (list 3 "c")) (list (list 1 "a") (list 4 "b") (list 3 "c")))
=> (list 2 1 3)
```

And I need it to give me

```
(list 2 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this in a simpler way:

1. append the lists to get only one list
2. create 2 result lists (initially empty): **dups** are the duplicates you found so far, and **res** are the unique keys you found so far
3. loop over the combined list; if the next key is either in dups or in the rest of the list then add it do dups, otherwise add it to res
4. when finished, return res

like so:

```
(define (unique-keys lst1 lst2)
  (let loop ((lst (append lst1 lst2)) (dups null) (res null))
    (if (null? lst)
        (reverse res)
        (let ((c (caar lst)))
          (if (or (member c dups) (assoc c (cdr lst)))
              (loop (cdr lst) (cons c dups) res)
              (loop (cdr lst) dups (cons c res)))))))
```

Testing:

```
> (unique-keys (list (list 1 "a") (list 2 "b") (list 3 "c")) (list (list 1 "a") (list 4 "b") (list 3 "c")))
(2 4)
```

Comment: If this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. If OTOH this does not answer your question then please get back to us.